# Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript

At first, sorry for my english, but can u tell me what am i doing wrong?
error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

```
// get 'hamburger' class from html
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');

// handle click on hamurger and add class 'hamburger-active' to it
function handleClick(){
    hamburger.classList.toggle('hamburger-active');
}
```

Comment: Share your HTML code

Comment: The error means that `document.querySelector` didn't find the element `.hamburger`. It's either because: a) that element doesn't exist, b) the class name provided has a typo, or c) the script runs before the element is created.

Comment: Most likely: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Where do you include the script? In the header or at the bottom of the body?

Answer (score 2):

An element with the class name `.hamburger` was not found, so the variable `hamburger` is `null`. Because the variable is `null`, you can't read its `classList` property (a `null` value doesn't have any properties).

To fix the error, ensure that the DOM contains an element with the class name `.hamburger` when the first line of your code (`const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');`) is run. You can add `console.log(hamburger);` to the next line to check the variable's value.

You can also check whether the variable is `null` before attempting to toggle the class `hamburger-active`:

```js
function handleClick(){
    if (hamburger !== null){
        hamburger.classList.toggle('hamburger-active');
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the explanation for the error. But why is this also an answer and not only a comment?

Comment: Ok, i understand, but the problem is that element with class .hamburger EXISTS in html so u know.